# wdContextMenu multi option

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

I'm trying to use "jquery wdContextMenu" multi-option and I've writed this code, but it doesn't work.
Can someone help me?
plz see "alert(thisoption);" it dosent work!
    $(function($) {

```
    function returnfalse() { return false; };
        $.fn.contextmenu = function(option) {
            var thiselement;
            var argumentCount = arguments.length,
                thisoption,
                elementType,
                menuoptions;
            $(this).each(function(e) {
                $(this).bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
                    elementType = $(this).prop('tagName').toLowerCase();
                    thisoption = parseInt($(elementType+"#"+this.id).attr("menu-option")-1);
                });
            }); 
            alert(thisoption);
            menuoptions = $.extend({alias: "cmroot", width: 'auto'}, arguments[thisoption]);
            var ruleName = null, target = null,
```

---

OK.. please see live example:
Corectly Original DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/a7sj4/
it is worked by this call:

```
$("#target,#target2,#target3").contextmenu(option});
```

Changed by me DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/PxzRW/
it is not work by this call:

```
$("#target,#target2,#target3").contextmenu(option1, option2});
```

---

1. the jquery plugins are exist in my page
2. yes this is part of my code...

my code worked corectly by one option(menu option string)... 
but when i try to load multi (menu option) this is not work... please see eg:
this is original code and worked corectly:

```
$("#thisrow).contextmenu(option1);
```

this is my code and not work corectly:

```
$("#thisrow,#pannelHome,#pannelFolders").contextmenu(option1, option2, option3);
```

Comment: What do you think your problem is? Any errors in the console? Why don' t you try posting a fiddle of what you are trying to do...

Comment: it is only load default argument(argument[0])... but i try get new argument and that is loaded by "thisoption" but not passed to "menuoption = $extend(....."

Comment: plz see "alert(thisoption);" it dosent work!

Comment: Have you tried to do what is in my answer? Why do you posted part of the plugin code? Did you write any code at all?

Comment: the jquery plugins are exist in my page
    yes this is part of my code...

my code worked corectly by one option(menu option string)... but when i try to load multi (menu option) this is not work... please see eg: this is original code and worked corectly:.... please see live examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. You've posted part of the code of the plugin you are trying to use, I don't know if that is what you intented to do, or you are completely lost. I recommend you to download [this](http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins-demo/wdContextMenu/src/Plugins/jquery.contextmenu.js) file. And then include it after a jquery distribution. like this, in a HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path_to_jquery"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path_to_wdContextMenuPlugin"></script>
```

After that, you are able to use the plug-in like in one of this examples:

[Examples](http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins-demo/wdContextMenu/sample.htm)